# How to enter debug mode when a condition is met?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, conditional-statements

Is there a way to enter debug mode when a certain condition is met?

For example let's say I would want to enter debug mode on the line on which `i == 1` becomes true:

```
using System;

namespace ConditionalDebug
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new Random();
            var i = r.Next(2);
            i += r.Next(2);
            i += r.Next(2);
            i += r.Next(2);
            i += r.Next(2);
            i = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to set conditional breakpoints like:

[image: conditional breakpoint]

But of course I couldn't use that since I would have to add a conditional breakpoint for each line in the code where the condition value might get changed and that would get very messy in a real application.

So, is there a way to globally set the condition `i == 1` so that the debugger will break on the line on which the condition is met?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is 'No'

The long answer is 'Not really, but kinda'.  There are things you can do to get close to the behaviour you want.

- You can use the Watch window and manually step through code and see it change.
- You can find all references on the variable and isolate all the statements that can change your variable and place break points.
- You could do the above, but use a wrapper function (or make it a Property) and only set the variable's value through that function (or property setter) then you have a single point where you can set your conditional break-point to compare the old/new value.
- You could put a break point on EVERY line and set the condition for all of them at once.  You might be able to automate that by writing a VS Plug-in or Macro.
- It's beyond me - but I'm sure it is possible to do something amazingly complex and awesome like write your own debugger and implement your 'Break whenever X Changes'.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer :D I like the idea: `You could put a break point on EVERY line and set the condition for all of them at once. You might be able to automate that by writing a VS Plug-in or Macro.`

Answer (score 1):

In VS's breakpoints window it is possible to select multiple breakpoints, and then with the right mouse button you can set a certain condition on both of them in one step.

Is that ok for you?

Comment: Thanks, it is an useful information but it would be almost impossible for real projects with lots of lines of code. :) What I would need would be the equivalent of having a conditional breakpoint on every line in the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, if you think about it you are asking the debugger to validate every line of code where i is in scope although i will watch this to see if anybody can think of a work around because it would be interesting to see :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to find out if it is possible: for the debugger to check the condition after *every* line of code in the solution.