# Alternative for VB6 "Add Watch" Feature in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

In Visual Studio later versions, I'm looking for a debugging feature similar to VB6's "Add Watch." This feature would automatically set breakpoints when specific conditions are met during runtime.

I've explored conditional execution, but it focuses on checking conditions at existing breakpoints, not before execution.
Is there a way to achieve this in Visual Studio?
I'm open to default settings, macros, or third-party extensions for setting automatic breakpoints based on conditions globally.

I've already looked into:

1. VB Forum Solution: Setting breakpoints within property setters, but it's challenging for many variables in a large codebase.
   [link1](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?612123-RESOLVED-How-to-break-when-watch-value-changes)
   [link2](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?645045-Break-When-a-Variable-Change)
2. Stack Overflow Forum Solution: Data breakpoints aren't available for managed code in Visual Studio 2019 or earlier
   Tracing variable changes manually - using watch, local or find all reference, but it's impractical for numerous variables.
   Another idea was to track variable usage, store values in an auxiliary variable, and trigger DebugBreak() when values change. However, this approach also becomes impractical with many variables in a large codebase.
   Links:
   [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160045/break-when-a-value-changes-using-the-visual-studio-debugger)
   [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945984/how-to-enter-debug-mode-when-a-condition-is-met)

None of the above solutions worked for me
I've posted my query on both in the VB forum and the Microsoft forum.

The VB Forum:
I shared my question but didn't come across any pertinent solutions. The property approach suggested there involves monitoring a single variable at a time and requires specifying the variable initially.
[VB forum](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?900910-Setting-Automatic-Breakpoints-a-vb6-Feature-in-Visual-Studio-later-versions&p=5615586#post5615586)

The Microsoft Forum:
In this forum, suggested data breakpoints not applicable to C#/VB
[Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1359151/alternative-for-vb6-add-watch-feature-in-visual-st)

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations on achieving this functionality. Thank you for your help!